# $urlRouterProvider.otherwise not going to default route

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am stuck with this for a while. I am very much new to ui-router's nesting of views. I am trying to route to default when "/" accessed. Here's my js file:

```
angular
        .module("app")
        .config(function($stateProvider,$locationProvider,$urlRouterProvider){

            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("dashboard");

            $stateProvider
                    .state("home",{
                        url: "/",
                        templateUrl: "views/home/home.html"
                    })

                    .state("login",{
                        url: "/login",
                        templateUrl: "views/login/login.html"
                    })

                    .state("home.dashboard",{
                        url: "/dashboard",
                        templateUrl: "views/home/dashboard.html"
                    });       
             $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

I don't know why that's not working. Every time I try to load `localhost`, it's not going to `localhost/dashboard`. Rather, it stops loading till `home.html`. Please help me in learning something new and showing my mistake.

Comment: yes. same result

Comment: Try changing `url` of `home.dashboard` state to `""`. Also include `abstract: true` to `home` state.

Comment: @MohammedSafwan sir, though it seems to be a workaround of the issue. But it doesn't shows the `/dashboard` url ?

Answer (score 0):

Please see this [working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Y5V8B8b3AaKuIPhC98nA?p=preview). I turned off the HTML5 mode because it prevents plunker to work correctly.

The main problem with your code was that you were redirecting to `/dashboard`, in this statement:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/dashboard");
```

Please note that `home.dashboard` is a child state of `home`. So, by default, the URL should be preceded by that of the `home` state. So the correct statement would be:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home/dashboard");
```

If you don't want the preceding `/home`, you need the change your route configuration for `home.dashboard` state to this:

```
.state("home.dashboard", {
  url: "^/dashboard",
  templateUrl: "dashboard.html"
});
```

The preceding `^` makes the URL absolute and makes it free of any preceding parent state's URL. So now, the statement `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/dashboard");` will work as is.

After this change, the code could load the template `home.html` in the view. Further, you didn't have any `ui-view` directives in `home.html` in which the template of `home.dashboard` could load. So I added a `<div ui-view></div>` element in `home.html` to make it work correctly.

Comment: Nope not working. and i needed `home` state url to be`"/"`. you changed it to `/home`. I think it has to do something with `url: "/"` beacuse it works  totally fine with html5Mode set to false and it produces this url: `http://localhost/#/dashboard`

Comment: @Steve -- I didn't change any state's URL. I used whatever was in your plunker. But even if you change the home state's URL to `/`, you will still need to precede it with `/home` or use `^/dashboard` as dashboard state's URL. Turning off HTML5 mode is just for plunker; in your actual code, HTML5 mode should work fine.

Comment: believe me I changed whatever you said. But its still not working. Even in the browser's network section, the `dashboard.html`  doesn't show up.

Comment: @Steve -- Can you create a plunker out of your current code and update in your question? Did you take a look at my plunker; it is working as you expected.